# dump output from /dev/video0 to fifo file

Tags: linux, file, save, v4l2, mplayer

I am trying to pipe /dev/video0 to out.raw and then immediately read it in
omxplayer. But I am getting no picture in omxplayer (I tried the same with
mplayer out.raw -> Playing out.raw but no picture shown)

My commands:

```
mkfifo out.raw
mplayer tv:///dev/video0 -dumpstream -dumpfile out.raw &
omxplayer out.raw
```

Any idea why I am not getting picture?

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what your `video0` device is in this case, it makes a difference because mplayer will initialize it differently.

Secondly, in many cases you'll find that even changing `out.raw` to a normal file, mplayer will NOT write anything.

For my laptop webcam, using the following will correctly send data to the FIFO:
`mencoder tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:width=960:height=720:fps=15:outfmt=mjpeg -nosound -ovc copy -o out.fifo`

But, this specifies that MEncoder should read from the INPUT device with a format of MJPEG, and simply copy the frames to the fifo.

The player reading the FIFO not be prepared for truncated MJPEG, so you should instead try to transcode it: `-ovc x264  -of avi`.

Regardless, you're going to run into problems playing the FIFO more than once, unless the player is very careful how it handles truncated frames, and your output contains LOTS of keyframes.

If there is nothing reading from a FIFO, writes to it WILL eventually block.

Maybe if you clarify why you want to use a FIFO, there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would use VLC instead if that's possible.

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --sout=file/ps:go.mpg
```

- VLC works in the CLI as well (not only GUI) and it seems it's now called `cvlc` (TIL:)
- It can also transcode and stream via HTTP or multicast if you wish.

Ref: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Receive_and_Save_a_Stream/

**EDIT**
Alright, I tried on my ancient Linux Mint (vlc 2.0.6 and mplayer instead of omxplayer).  The mux=XXX can be another one of your choice, see [VLC Muxers](https://wiki.videolan.org/Codec/#Muxers)

```
mkfifo /tmp/out.raw
cvlc <video_input>  --sout="#duplicate{dst=std{access=file,dst='/tmp/out.raw',mux=avi},dst=nodisplay}" 
mplayer /tmp/out.raw
```

PS: I have not used VLC for years and the above is untested. I just had 5min to kill and found by luck your question I decided to answer.

Comment: VLC doesn't interact properly w/ the FIFO: `core input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting`